# I don't understand how jQuery .each() and .html() methods work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im Timo. I'm new at web programming and I have this issue. I have made a simple html table with 3 rows. Each td has to have a random numeric value. My problem is that my code puts the same value at every td element.

http://jsfiddle.net/timosergio/30ydu4oe/

Down below is my js code:

```
        $(function() {

            randomValues();
            //alert(1);
        });


    var randomValues = function(){
        var $td = $('.table').find('td');

        // each td has to have a different random value

        var random_values = Math.random() * 100 ;

        $td.each(function(i){

            //console.log(i + ":" + Math.random() * 100);

            $td.eq(i).text(random_values);

        });


    };
```

Comment: Don't take http://xkcd.com/221/ too literally. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This is because you're generating a single random value then using that for each of the `td`s, rather than generating a new one for each `td`. So:

```
$td.each(function(i){
    $td.eq(i).text(Math.random(Math.random() * 100));
});
```

In other words, generate the random value inside the loop, not outside of it.

Furthermore, understand that, inside `each` callbacks, the context, i.e. `this`, points to the element being considered. So you don't need

```
$td.eq(i).text(...
```

but merely

```
$(this).text(...
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept an answer if you deem one to have solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

[`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is essentially a foreach loop. You need to create a new random value on each iteration.

Like this:

```
var randomValues = function() {
  var $td = $('.table').find('td');

  // each td has to have a different random value
  $td.each(function(i){
    //console.log(i + ":" + Math.random() * 100);

    var random_value = Math.random() * 100 ;

    $td.eq(i).text(random_value);

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your random value is generated before the each statement, so the same value is being used each time.

Move your Math.random()*100 into your .text() and all should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with `.each()` or `.html()`. You have generated the random value just once and setting the same value to each of the td. You need to do this.

```
var randomValues = function(){
        var $td = $('.table').find('td');

        // each td has to have a different random value

       // var random_values = Math.random() * 100 ;

        $td.each(function(i){

            //console.log(i + ":" + Math.random() * 100);

            $td.eq(i).text(Math.random() * 100);

        });


    };
```

Comment: I see. Thank you so much!